# Failed login does not return to the correct page

Tags: asp.net

I have a website with a customized login page.

In web.config, I have the following code;

```
 <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <roleManager enabled="true" />
      <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Admin/login.aspx"  timeout="2880"></forms>
      </authentication>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
       <pages validateRequest="false"  />
      <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
      <membership>
        <providers>
          <clear/>
          <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="DetaySanConnectionString"
               enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
               maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
               applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
      </membership>
    </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
  </appSettings>
  <location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

Also, my admin folder denies anonymus entries.
This set up used to work for me but on this particular website when I try the link;

websiteurl.com/admin
it redirects me to

```
 websiteurl.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fadmin
```

when in fact, it should be

```
websiteurl.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fadmin
```

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To those who are curious the problem was solved by adding

`<add key="loginUrl" value="login.aspx"/>`

in web.config to appSettings.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `path="Admin"` and change `loginUrl="~/Admin/login.aspx"` and see what happens.

Also, check whether the Admin folder has a separate `web.config` that clashes with the one in the root of the site.

Comment: still the same error, Admin folder does have a web.config that denies the anonymus users with only these;

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: hmm, I wonder whether you have used visual studio to setup forms auth. you might have some hidden settings in the local db which vs creates and they are overriding your web.config.

Comment: Hmm, not sure, I add the login page and  authentication mode to web.config myself after I deny access to admin folder on asp.net configuration tool on visual studio.

Comment: Probably a language barrier here, but if I understand you correctly, you have disallowed access to admin folder using vs. did you provide any redirect information? have you ever specified anywhere the Account folder? have a look for any connections strings which you haven't added yourself, remove them and try running the site again. also to a ctrl+f in your entire solution for "Account" and see where it comes up in your search

Comment: When I started the project I picked the empty web project which actually never had a folder named account like the default web project option, and when I search the project It doesn't have anything called account anywhere.

Comment: I had one extra connection string which I hadn't added, removed it but  no change.

Comment: ok, i insist that there is something in your web.config that causes that, but try deleting the web.config in the Admin folder and add the following in the bottom of the root web.config
`<location path="Admin">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>`

Comment: Also, can you edit your question and include all of your web.config?

Comment: Ok, edited the code still didn't work with the latest suggestion I kept the connection strings out on purpose for this post as it includes sensitive data

Comment: so, yes, as i said, it's the web.config, the `AspNetSqlMembershipProvider` is causing all your troubles, try removing it... :)

Comment: That's not it unfortunately, still the same error when removed.

Comment: did you delete the whole `<membership>` node and the `<rolemanager>`? you have to go through the web.config and delete everything which you haven't added your self

Comment: yes, no use, for some reason it ignores the authentication part.

Comment: try this:
`<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="YOURNAME.FORMSAUTH" loginUrl="~/Admin/login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="60"/>
    </authentication>`

Comment: what should I write at "yourname" part?

Comment: you can write your site name, it's there to identify the cookie names that belong to your app

Comment: the problem solved by adding `<add key="loginUrl"value="login.aspx"/>` to appSettings. Thanks anyway for your effort :)